# Why does this keep throwing an exception error?

Tags: exception, javafx

So i am making this Lending Library program and everything seems to work fine except when deleting the last item in my listview, i have looked over it for about 3 hours now and cannot figure it out! for some reason it only does it when i delete that last item. please help, here is my code.

LendingLibraryGUI

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class LendingLibraryGUI extends Application {
    LendingLibrary LendingLibrary = new LendingLibrary(); //Creating an Object to access total numbers of items
    MediaItems Media = new MediaItems(); // creating an array of object to access MediaItems class and allowing it to hold 100 items 
    private ListView<String> library = new ListView<String>(); //Creates Listview
    ObservableList<String> libraryList = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(); //Creates a list to use in the Listview




    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane display = new BorderPane(); //Main display
        GridPane buttons = new GridPane(); //location to display buttons
        TextField outPut = new TextField(); //Text field to show inventory
        Insets padding = new Insets(10); //creates Insets for padding
        buttons.setPadding(padding); //padding around grid pane
        buttons.setHgap(10); //Horizontal gap
        libraryList = LendingLibrary.load(); //Loads contents from a txt file back into the listview
        library.setItems(libraryList); //inputs list of data into the listview


        for (int i =0; i !=4;i++) { //Loop to create Buttons
            String[] actionButtons = {"Add","Check Out","Check In","Delete"};//String to store Button names
            Button temp = new Button(actionButtons[i]); //creates a temp button
            temp.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE); //sets the size of buttons
            buttons.add(temp, i, 0); //add buttons to grid pane
            GridPane.setHgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);
            GridPane.setVgrow(temp, Priority.ALWAYS);

            if (temp.getText().equals("Add")) { //if add button is pushed
                temp.setOnAction((e) -> {
                    try {
                        add();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (temp.getText().equals("Delete")) { //if delete button is pushed
                library.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(ov -> { //gets the selected item from the listview
                temp.setOnAction((e) -> {
                        if(libraryList.isEmpty()) {

                        }
                        else {
                        try {
                            deleteLibrary();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }

                });
                });
            }
            else if (temp.getText().equals("Check Out")){ //if check out button is pushed

                library.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(ov -> { //gets the selected item from the listview
                    String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //stores selected listview data into a string

                    temp.setOnAction((e) -> { { // when checkout button is pushed


                                if (name.contains(" is currently on loaned to ")) {
                                    errorMessage("Currently on Loan");
                                }
                                else {

                                    inputGUI("Who did you loan this to?");
                                }



                        }
                    });
                });

            }
            else if (temp.getText().equals("Check In")) {
                library.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(ov -> { //gets the selected item from the listview
                    String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //stores selected listview data into a string

                    temp.setOnAction((e) -> { { // when checkout button is pushed


                                if (!name.contains(" is currently on loaned to ")) { //Catch if the item is not on loan
                                    errorMessage("Not on Loan");
                                }
                                else {
                                    try {
                                        checkIn();
                                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }



                        }
                    });
                });



            }



    }


    outPut.setEditable(false); //no editing
    outPut.setFont(Font.font("monospace", FontWeight.BOLD, 20)); //sets fonts
    outPut.setMinHeight(300);//sets minimum height
    display.setTop(library); //sets output in display on top
    display.setCenter(buttons); //sets buttons on center 


    Scene scene = new Scene(display); //creates new scene
    primaryStage.setTitle("Lending Library"); //sets title of GUI
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); //adds scene to GUI
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(500); //Minimum height
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(400);//Minimum Width
    primaryStage.show();//Displays GUI to user
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}


private void add() throws IOException { //adding items to the library
    inputGUI("Title:"); //input method

    try {
        LendingLibrary.Save(library); //updates save of media
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void inputGUI(String input) { //input method to put information into the list

    Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    VBox titlePane = new VBox(8);
    HBox buttonLayout = new HBox(8);
    Label lblTitle = new Label(input);
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    Button close = new Button("Close");
    Insets padding = new Insets(10);
    TextField txt = new TextField("");
    close.setOnAction((e) -> secondaryStage.close());; //close button closes secondary stage



    save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { //Save button to save information
        @Override 
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            if (txt.getText().trim().isEmpty()) { //if text field is empty do nothing
                errorMessage("Please Enter Data into the text area"); //tells user to enter data in text field
            }
            else {

                if (input.equals("Title:")) { //gets the title of media
                    Media.setTitle(txt.getText()); //sets title of media
                    secondaryStage.close(); 
                    inputGUI("Format:"); //calls inputGUI to get format of media
                }
                else if (input.equals("Format:")) { //gets the format of media
                    Media.setFormat(txt.getText()); //sets format of media
                    secondaryStage.close();
                    addToLibrary(); //adds media to library
                }
                else if (input.equals("Who did you loan this to?")) { //gets information on who borrowed the media
                    Media.setLoan(txt.getText()); //sets loaned out
                    secondaryStage.close();
                    inputGUI("When did you loan it(date)?"); //gets date when media was borrowed
                }
                else if (input.equals("When did you loan it(date)?")) { //gets date when media was borrowed
                    Media.setDate(txt.getText());//sets date when media was borrowed
                    secondaryStage.close();
                    checkOut(); //checks out media from library

                }
            }
            try {
                LendingLibrary.Save(library); //updates save of media
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });



    buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(close,save);
    titlePane.setPadding(padding);
    titlePane.getChildren().addAll(lblTitle,txt,buttonLayout);
    border.setCenter(titlePane);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(titlePane, Pos.CENTER);

    Scene scene = new Scene(border); //creates new scene
    secondaryStage.setTitle("Input"); //sets title of GUI
    secondaryStage.setScene(scene); //adds scene to GUI
    secondaryStage.setMinHeight(200); //Minimum height
    secondaryStage.setMinWidth(350);//Minimum Width
    secondaryStage.setMaxHeight(200); //Minimum height
    secondaryStage.setMaxWidth(350);//Minimum Width

    secondaryStage.show();//Displays GUI to user


}


private void addToLibrary() { //adding media to library
    String total; //string to hold name and format of media

    total = Media.getTitle();
    total = total + " ("+ Media.getFormat() +")";
    libraryList.add(total); //adds media to list
    library.setItems(libraryList); //adds list to library



}

private void deleteLibrary() throws IOException { //deletes media from library

        int selectedItem = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); //gets selected item in library list
        libraryList.remove(selectedItem); //removes media from list
        LendingLibrary.Save(library); //updates save of media

        }






private void checkOut(){ //checkout method for media
    String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //grabs name of media selected
    int selectedItem = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); //grabs location of media in list
    libraryList.remove(selectedItem); //removes selected media
    libraryList.add(name + " | is currently on loaned to " + Media.getLoan() + " on " + Media.getDate()); //add media back to list 

}

private void checkIn() throws IOException { //check in method for media

    String temp = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //grabs name of media selected
    String data = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("|") -1); //splits data up
    temp = temp.replace(data, ""); //removes checked out

    int selectedItem = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); //grabs location of media
    libraryList.remove(selectedItem); //removes media
    libraryList.add(temp); //adds data back in
    try {
        LendingLibrary.Save(library); //updates save of media
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
private void errorMessage(String message) { //displays error messages
    Stage errorStage = new Stage();
    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    VBox titlePane = new VBox(8);
    HBox buttonLayout = new HBox(8);
    Label lblTitle = new Label(message); //displays reason of error
    Button close = new Button("Close");
    Insets padding = new Insets(10);
    close.setOnAction((e) -> errorStage.close());;
    buttonLayout.getChildren().addAll(close);
    buttonLayout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    titlePane.setPadding(padding);
    titlePane.getChildren().addAll(lblTitle,buttonLayout);
    titlePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    border.setCenter(titlePane);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(titlePane, Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(border); //creates new scene
    errorStage.setTitle("Error"); //sets title of GUI
    errorStage.setScene(scene); //adds scene to GUI
    errorStage.setMinHeight(200); //Minimum height
    errorStage.setMinWidth(350);//Minimum Width
    errorStage.setMaxHeight(200); //Minimum height
    errorStage.setMaxWidth(350);//Minimum Width
    errorStage.show();//Displays GUI to user

}
}
```

LendingLibrary

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;


public class LendingLibrary{


    public void Save(ListView<String> library) throws IOException { //saves library as text file

        String joined = library.getItems().stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        File file = new File("LendingLibrary.txt");//Creates the text file Calc
        file.createNewFile(); //if file doesnt exist it will create it (if it does nothing will happen)

        if(file.exists()) { //if the file exists

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(joined);
            if(!file.exists()) { //if file doesn't exist
                System.out.println("Error creating file");

            }
            output.close();
        }



    }




    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public ObservableList<String> load() throws FileNotFoundException { //loads information into program


        ObservableList<String> libraryList = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(); //creates a list
        File file = new File ("LendingLibrary.txt"); //access the file

        if(file.exists()) { //if file does exist 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        input.useDelimiter(","); //Separates data by a comma 

        while (input.hasNext()) { //while the list has data

            String temp = input.next(); //stores data into a string
            temp = temp.trim(); //trims spaces from beginning of data
            if (temp.equals("")) {

            }
            else {
            libraryList.addAll(temp); //stores data into the list 
            }

        }


        }
        else if(!file.exists()) { //if does not file exist

        }
        return libraryList; //returns list to use in the listview

    }


    }
```

MediaItems

```
public class MediaItems { 
private String title;
private String format;
private String loanedTo;
private String dateLoaned;

public void setTitle(String name) {title = name;}
public void setFormat(String type) {format = type;}

public String getTitle() {return title;}
public String getFormat() {return format;}


public void setLoan(String loaned) {loanedTo = loaned;}
public String getLoan() {return loanedTo; }


public void setDate(String date) {dateLoaned = date;}
public String getDate() {return dateLoaned;}
}
```

Not sure if it matters but here is the exception it throws, it doesnt actually crash the program or anything just an error it throws when i delete the last item...

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LendingLibraryGUI.lambda$3(LendingLibraryGUI.java:85)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearSelection(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:682)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel$2.onChanged(ListView.java:1222)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:183)
    at LendingLibraryGUI.deleteLibrary(LendingLibraryGUI.java:266)
    at LendingLibraryGUI.lambda$2(LendingLibraryGUI.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LendingLibraryGUI.lambda$5(LendingLibraryGUI.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearSelection(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:682)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel$2.onChanged(ListView.java:1222)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.remove(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:183)
    at LendingLibraryGUI.deleteLibrary(LendingLibraryGUI.java:266)
    at LendingLibraryGUI.lambda$2(LendingLibraryGUI.java:72)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are lines 85 and 107 in `LendingLibraryGUI`?

Comment: line 85 is 
   String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //stores selected listview data into a string

Comment: and line 107 is 
String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString(); //stores selected listview data into a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To:

```
String name = library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

library.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() is null -- i.e. you are dereferencing a null pointer!

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed my problem! It makes sense now that i know where i messed up!